# setForceSelection(false) is not working in gxt combobox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have an editable Gxt Combobox. When i type something and click submit button, the value is not getting retained. It becomes empty on blur. I have set the forceselection property to false. But still it is not working. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

```
 final ComboBox<Search> searchComboBox = new ComboBox<Search>(searchStore, searchProperties.searchText());
 searchComboBox.setWidth(100);
 searchComboBox.setForceSelection(false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GXT Combobox : type a value that is not in the list and keep it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148483/gxt-combobox-type-a-value-that-is-not-in-the-list-and-keep-it)

Comment: @JonSampson, I tried the link which you have given. But it is not working.

Comment: Either that custom subclass can work (I'm using it in my own project, I know it works, share the code that doesn't work with it if you want help), or adapt your code to use the StringComboBox which supports this idea as a specific feature.

Comment: Are you trying to add/type a value which is currently not present in the store of the combobox? If yes, it would definitely be cleared on blur.